# How to rename a database in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

On the api documentation page [rethinkdb.com/api/javascript](http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript) I can only find commands to create, drop and list databases.

But how I can I rename a database in RethinkDB?

Comment: This was removed from the UI in a recent rewrite, but it should come back eventually (https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/3825) is the issue to track if you're interested

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You basically have two options:

**1. Update the name using the `.config` method**

You can also update the name using the `.config` method every database and tables has. This would look something like this:

```
r
  .db("db_name")
  .config()
  .update({name: "new_db_name"})
```

**2. Update the `db_config` table**

You can also execute a query on the `db_config` table and just do an update on the db you want to change. This would look something like this:

```
r   
   .db('rethinkdb')   
   .table('db_config')   
   .filter({ name: 'old_db_name' })   
   .update({ name: 'new_table_name'})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to get mentioned in the documentation at all. -.-

Comment: For anyone else finding this the last query should actually be:

`r.db('rethinkdb').table('table_config').filter({name: 'old_table_name'}).update({name: 'new_table_name'})`